# Bash - Grep an inputted pattern and return line number to variable

Tags: bash

I am trying figure out how I can ask a user for input, use the input as the pattern to match with grep, and return the line number to a variable.

```
echo "What BCP do you want?"
read BCPid   # Get what value we're interested in.

for i in *.txt
do
  BCPlinenum=$(echo "$BCPid" | (grep -n "$BCPid" |cut -f1 -d:))
  echo "$BCPlinenum"
done
```

This returns a value of 1, regardless of what I input.

The file it searches looks as follows,

```
BCP C1 C2
BCP C1 C3
BCP C1 C4
BCP C2 C3
BCP C2 C4
BCP C3 C4
```

So, the desired function is to input "BCP C1 C2" and have it return 1 (the line number) to a variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually feeding your input file into `grep`.

Change

```
BCPlinenum=$(echo "$BCPid" | (grep -n "$BCPid" |cut -f1 -d:))
```

to

```
BCPlinenum=$(grep -n -e "$BCPid" <"$i" | cut -f1 -d:)
```

or

```
BCPlinenum=$(grep -n -e "$BCPid" -- "$i" | cut -f1 -d:)
```

Comment: why `-e` and `<` or `--` instead of just `grep -n "$BCPid" "$i"`?

Comment: @webb, what if you have a filename that starts with a `-` and thus could look like a flag? Using `--` makes the command-line parsing unambiguous.

Comment: @webb, ...the `-e` is there for the exact same reason, for the case where your *id* starts with a dash.

Comment: @webb, ...re: the former, see guideline 10 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html (so any POSIX-compliant `grep` is required to honor that end-of-options sigil); `-e` is similarly POSIX-specified, in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html.

Answer (score 0):

here it is, no loop required:

```
echo "What BCP do you want?"
read BCPid   # Get what value we're interested in.
results=`grep -nH "$BCPid" *.txt | cut -f1,2 -d:`
```

you can use a loop (or something better) to handle the output:

```
grep -nH "$BCPid" *.txt | cut -f1,2 -d: |
  while IFS=: read file n; do
    echo "found match in file $file on line $n"
  done
```

Comment: You might want `while IFS=: read -r file n`; otherwise, it'll be trying to split into variables on whitespace rather than colons (and backslashes in the names will potentially muck things up). And I *do* advise making it `grep -n -e "$BCPid" -- *.txt` -- which still isn't perfect, will fail with filenames with colons, but being able to correctly parse all possible filenames from `grep`'s output unambiguously requires a grep with `--null`, which means a dependency on GNU tools which may not be desired.

Comment: oops, thanks. fixed the missing IFS. and thanks for the info about `-e` and `--`. if you'd like i can share a script that finds if anyone has named a file with a colon, leading dash, or space, and replaces the contents of those files with a stern admonishment ;)

Comment: thinking about it further, even safer would be `-- /dev/null *.txt` -- otherwise, it'll behave badly if there's only one text file (doesn't print filenames if there's only one file passed, absent an explicit `-H`).

Comment: ...as for the stern-admonishment approach, to summarize my philosophy: You can't fix the world, you can only fix your code. (Pretend that you have the world you want instead of the world you *actually do* have, and you get bugs in the corners you conveniently ignored -- so better to take the realist's approach).